# Why do I get Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object...?

Tags: php

I am making a game for class and I have added a commenting system to go with it. I am now wanting to add the ability to report the comment.

I have added a column in the comments table called report_active and my idea was to set this to 1 when it is active (meaning it has been reported) and 0 when it isn't. Then just list in the adminCP all of the comments with an active report on them.

I have made a file called `report_comment.php` which I intend to only be used to run the queries then redirect back to another page.

This is my `report_comment.php`page:

```
<?php
require_once('db_connect.php');
require_once('security.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $report_active = 1;
        $id            = $_GET['id'];

        $select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = ?");
        $select->bind_param('i', $id);
        if ($select->execute()) {
                if ($select->num_rows) {
                        // Run the update query
                        $update = $db->query("UPDATE comments SET report_active = ? WHERE id = ?");
                        $update->bind_param('ii', $report_active, $id);
                        if ($update->execute()) {
                                header('Location: comments.php');
                                die();
                        }
                }
        }
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? As this is the error I am returned with:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`

Comment: You must `prepare` to `bind` anything. And you can not `bind` after you `query`.

Comment: You intend to call `prepare()`, not `query()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = ?");
               ^^^^^---execute the query immediately
```

You want

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id = ?");
             ^^^^^^^---note the diff
```

instead. Plus, you should be checking for failure, e.g.

```
if ($stmt === false) {
   die("Prepare failed with error: " . $db->errorInfo);
}
```

or similar for your particular DB library.

Comment: Oh yeah, I copied and pasted from one of my other files. I really need to fully read my code :) Thanks